# Android suitable Layout to hold Tile views or Grid views with drag & move, context menu functions?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-view

I'm creating following screen using Android layouts in xml. Requirement is :

[image]

According to the album selection made on the drop down list I need to populate the Song tiles. Each Song tile should have their own click even and on long press event to show 'context menu'(to rename, add to playlist etc..). Also users should be able to drag and move the song tiles to their desired position in tiles list(swapping the song position). Song tiles should be inside a scroll view.

**My question is** by considering all these requirements, can anyone suggest me that, which could be the best and suitable layout for song titles? Of course I will use fragment to control 'song titles area' in each selected album.
I don't need a completed design. I just need the idea of how I can approach it?

Especially ideas on selecting layout for titles view with the features of 
drag & move title, separate on click & on long press events.

Note : on an the event of renaming a song title## Heading ##, modification should reflect immediately without recreating the entire fragment/activity.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop is suitable for any View / ViewGroup or subclasses. 
Use the Drag and Drop framework of android.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

For a smoother behaviour, consider using a recyclerView attached to a gridView layout. Then, each tile or item of your recyclerView can be a fragment directly.
When you will use drag and drop, you can treat them as simple View (cast fragment into view). When changing position after drop, you can re-inflate fragement at the right position thanks to the Drag And Drop framework.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go for a GridView. You can use [this](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView) library.